# How to prevent the kernel to killing the python process

Tags: python, ubuntu, concurrency, linux-kernel

Recently I ran a python script. It's run on a pandas dataframe with nearly 70000 rows and calls a local server request in the `apply` function.
I used `Pool` to concurrent this script with the below method:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=4):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df
```

But when I ran this code with all CPU cores. after a while, all of my processes stopped (maybe killed by the kernel)

How can I prevent the kernel from killing these processes?

Comment: It could be using all the available memory. Print the PIDs(`import os; os.getpid()`) of parent and child processes and track their memory usage using ps/top/Process Monitor.

Comment: Yes, it might. But I want the kernel didn't kill these processes even in that case.

Comment: If high memory is the cause, you should explore techniques that loads and process the dataframe in batches instead of loading the entire dataframe into memory at once. You could also look into [dask](https://dask.org/).

Comment: *"But I want the kernel didn't kill these processes even in that case"* - well there's not much you can do. Either the kernel kills those processes or it panics and crashes because it does not have the memory needed to continue operating. In both cases the processes end up being killed, it's just that in the second case you also have to reboot your machine.